# Angular unable to display API results in html

Tags: html, json, angular, api

In Angular, why am I unable to display the results from an API call?

The JSON returned from the API call. I want to display the value attribute.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APALE"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "9695006WHN4DWDKBF403"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/9695006WHN4DWDKBF403"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APPLITEC"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "AppLogic"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "724500S2JQ8M9Q67N911"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/724500S2JQ8M9Q67N911"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APPRECIO"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "969500ZFBM0TC2T1HV85"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/969500ZFBM0TC2T1HV85"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "AMPLEGEST"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "969500DYMLRK8URCGP47"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/969500DYMLRK8URCGP47"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "ANPLEX OÜ"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "254900RNJSFWJXOZE551"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/254900RNJSFWJXOZE551"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "Apleks OÜ"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "254900VZB706EXH22533"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/254900VZB706EXH22533"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APPLE-WAY"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "969500QV2N8IIVULLH93"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/969500QV2N8IIVULLH93"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APPLICOMM"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "969500MCJ58VYVTX3715"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/969500MCJ58VYVTX3715"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "fuzzycompletions",
      "attributes": {
        "value": "APPLIQ AS"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "lei-records": {
          "data": {
            "type": "lei-records",
            "id": "8945006S1SZMS8HKLR20"
          },
          "links": {
            "related": "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/lei-records/8945006S1SZMS8HKLR20"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a service.ts file for connecting to the API

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class GleifService {

  private gleifUrl = 'https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/fuzzycompletions?field=entity.legalName&q=';  // URL to web api
  private data:any = []

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getGleif(name: string){
    const url = `${this.gleifUrl}${name}`;
    this.http.get(url).subscribe((res)=>{
      this.data = res
      console.log(this.data)
    })
  }

}
```

A component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { GleifService } from '../gleif.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-security',
  templateUrl: './security.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./security.component.css']
})
export class SecurityComponent implements OnInit {

  // array for storing the data
  private data:any = []

  constructor(private gleifService: GleifService) { }

  getGleif(name: string): void {
    this.data = this.gleifService.getGleif(name);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getGleif(name);
  }

}
```

And a .html file for displaying the results

```
<div>
  <label>Company ID:
    <input placeholder="Autofill"/>
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Company Name:
    <input #Name placeholder="A Company Ltd"/>
    <button (click)="getGleif(Name.value); Name.value=''">Search</button>
  </label>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let entry of data?.data" style="text-align:center">
  <h3>
     header works: {{ entry.type }}
   </h3>
</div>
```

I can see the results in the console response. How can I access and display results from the API call?

Comment: Maybe it's because `getGleif(name: string)` in `GleifService` doesn't `return` anything? That function only sets a local variable. Something to read: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are subscribing your http call from your service instead of returning it's data. Once you have subscribed the call in your service, no data will be returned unless you return the observable value from your http and let the component subscribe it's response or data

Update your code instead to:

**Service**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

...

getGleif(name: string): Observable<any> {
  const url = `${this.gleifUrl}${name}`;
    
  return this.http.get(url);
}
```

**Component**

```
...

getGleif(name: string): void {
  this.gleifService
    .getGleif(name)
    .subscribe(res => this.data = res); 
}
```

---

or in your **Component** you could also do this:

```
...

data$: Observable<any>;

getGleif(name: string): void {
  this.data$ = this.gleifService.getGleif(name);    // we have assigned it with an Observable variable since the return of this service is of Observable type that needed to be subscribe into
}
```

**Template**

```
...

// Since the data$ is async, we use pipe async to fetch it's raw data
<div *ngFor="let entry of (data$ | async)?.data" style="text-align:center">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to subscribe to the result in the `component.ts` file

```js
getGleif(name: string): void {
    this.gleifService.getGleif(name).subscribe((result) => {
        this.data = result
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to return the data from the service and subscribe inside the component file.
and you don't need to call the function inside ngOnInit because you are going to call it when search button is clicked.

componet.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { GleifService } from "./service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  // array for storing the data
  private data: any = [];

  constructor(private gleifService: GleifService) {}

  getGleif(name: string): void {
    this.gleifService.getGleif(name).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.data = response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

component.html file

```
<div>
  <label
    >Company ID:
    <input placeholder="Autofill" />
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label
    >Company Name:
    <input #Name placeholder="A Company Ltd" />
    <button (click)="getGleif(Name.value); Name.value=''">Search</button>
  </label>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let entry of data" style="text-align: center;">
  <h3>
    header works: {{ entry.type }}
  </h3>
</div>
```

service.ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class GleifService {
  private gleifUrl =
    "https://api.gleif.org/api/v1/fuzzycompletions?field=entity.legalName&q="; // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getGleif(name: string) {
    const url = `${this.gleifUrl}${name}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-stackoverflow-m89k2)